# Create a new environment that uses a verbatim environment

Tags: color, environments, verbatim

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{color}
\NewEnviron{vred}{%
\color{red}
\begin{verbatim}
  \BODY
\end{verbatim}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{vred}
test
\end{vred}
\end{document}
```

Compiling with `pdflatex` gives the error:

```
Runaway argument?
\end {document} 
! Paragraph ended before \next was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.16
```

Comment: This is defined as the age-old problem of trying to pass `verbatim` content as a macro argument, which requires special treatment. Perhaps you could elaborate on what you're after really.

Comment: I want to make an environment for red verbatim text..

Comment: With [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings): `\lstnewenvironment{vred}{<something before the verbatim part>}{<something after>}`. This command also allows to add arguments the same way `\newenvironment` does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this particular case the problem is a typical one: You can't pass `verbatim` content as an argument to another macro. This is indeed the case with using [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ), since content is accumulated in the macro `\BODY` for processing later.

From the looks of your minimal example, it seems like you're after printing `verbatim` content using a specific colour (say red). For this I'd suggest defining a new verbatim environment with this specific quality/attribute. As such, [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) can come in handy. Here's a MWE that illustrates this concept (taken, virtually *verbatim*, from the [`fancyvrb` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.pdf) (section **4.1.3 Customization of formatting**, p 5 and **4.2.4 Personalized environments**, p 18)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{fancyvrb,xcolor}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment%
  {MyVerbatim}{Verbatim}
  {formatcom=\color{red}}
\begin{document}
\begin{MyVerbatim}
First verbatim line.
Second verbatim line.
\end{MyVerbatim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you pass a parameter (#1) to the environment such that before the red verbatim text we also insert a `\subsection*{#1}`.. (which should not be in red) ?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding my last comment to `Werner`s answer, I found the following to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,xcolor}
\newenvironment{MyVerbatim}[1]{
  \subsection*{#1}\VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{Verbatim}[formatcom=\color{red}]}{\end{Verbatim}}
\begin{document}
\begin{MyVerbatim}{A verbatim subsection}
 First verbatim line.
 Second verbatim line.
\end{MyVerbatim}
\end{document}
```